# Basic Django - How do view wrappers receive the request, keyword and positional arguments?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-templates, django-views

In [chapter 8](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter08/) of the [Django book](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter08/) there is an example showing a fundamental view wrap method, which receives another view method passed in from any single arbitrary URLconf:

```
def requires_login(view):
    def new_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated():
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/login/')
        return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return new_view
```

I follow most of the logic here, but what I'm not understanding is how the nested `new_view` definition is receiving the request, *args and **kwargs as it's not being explicitly passed into the `requires_login` definition.

How exactly is the `new_view` definition receiving these arguments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### How `new_view` works

Let's first look at the `new_view` function:

```
def new_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/login/')
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

When `new_view` is called, it checks whether the user is authenticated. If the user is authenticated, then `new_view` calls `view` and passes it all of the arguments (`request`, positional arguments, and keyword arguments).

### Defining new_view

`new_view` is not automatically executed. We are using `def` to define the function, but we are not executing it right away. Instead, we return `new_view` as a function. Imagine the following code:

```
def my_view(request):
    # ... some view stuff happens here

my_new_view = requires_login(my_view)
```

Now, `my_new_view` is a function. I can call it just like any other function. At no point so far has this new function actually been called.

When `my_new_view` is called, it receives all its arguments. It then calls `my_view`, passing all the arguments (`request`, positional arguments, and keyword arguments) to `my_view` instead.

(All of this assumes that the user is authenticated, of course. Otherwise, when you call `my_new_view`, you would get an `HttpResponseRedirect`, and `my_view` would never be called.)

### `view` as an argument

`requires_login` receives a function called `view` as its argument. `view` refers to a function, but we're not executing that function yet. `view` is executed only when `new_view` is executed.

Comment: Bingo, that's the one. How did I not see this...? Haha. Make perfect sense now. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it makes sense. If you haven't looked into Python decorators yet, now would be a great time. Decorators are just functions that accept a function as an argument and return a function, just like `requires_login` here.